# the new auto keyword pointer does delete itself?

Tags: c++, pointers, auto

If I have this line

```
auto* f = new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S");
```

do I have to delete the pointer? or it cleans up itself?

```
delete f; // ??
```

I know that auto_ptr and shared_ptr are deleted automatically, but I don't know about auto

Comment: auto only deduces the type for you, it doesn't do anything else.

Comment: *"If I have this line"* You should not have this line. Use RAII. If you must use pointers, use smart pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auto` has nothing to do with `auto_ptr`, it just tells the compiler to deduce a type.

So yes, in the example you provide, `delete` is needed.

Slightly off-topic : you mention `auto_ptr` (this one is deprecated) and `shared_ptr`, but there is also `unique_ptr` which is quite handy because it's very lightweight (practically no overhead), and can be used when there is a single owner.